# Saved password store on Android Edge browser

Tags: passwords, web-browser, android, microsoft-edge

Does anyone have knowledge, or better yet, a reference document showing how and where passwords are stored when using the Edge browser on Android?

I'm assuming it's going to be SQLite, as I understand Chrome does on Android, but looking for any one who may have seen this before?

Comment: The fact that passwords are synced between devices (both phones and desktop) implies that they can be stored / transferred in the cloud, attached to your Microsoft Account.

Comment: Hi, I agree that there is cloud storage of the passwords. However, as you get the option to save passwords on the Android variant, without being logged in, there must be local storage of them on the device, which is then optionally sync’d. Right?